# Write a string to a file

Tags: android, streamwriter

I want to write something to a file. I found this code:

```
private void writeToFile(String data) {
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(context.openFileOutput("config.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        outputStreamWriter.write(data);
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
    } 
}
```

The code seems very logical, but I can't find the config.txt file in my phone.
How can I retrieve that file which includes the string?

Comment: Do you really need to write something into a txt file? If not consider using SharedPreferences. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Not having specified a **path**, your file will be saved in your app space (`/data/data/your.app.name/`).

Therefore, you better save your file onto an external storage (which is not necessarily the SD card, it can be the default storage).

You might want to dig into the subject, by reading the [official docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal)

In synthesis:

Add this permission to your Manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

It includes the READ permission, so no need to specify it too.

Save the file in a location you specify (this is taken from my live cod, so I'm sure it works):

```
public void writeToFile(String data)
{
    // Get the directory for the user's public pictures directory.
    final File path =
        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
        (
            //Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + "/YourFolder/"
        );

    // Make sure the path directory exists.
    if(!path.exists())
    {
        // Make it, if it doesn't exit
        path.mkdirs();
    }

    final File file = new File(path, "config.txt");

    // Save your stream, don't forget to flush() it before closing it.

    try
    {
        file.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        myOutWriter.append(data);

        myOutWriter.close();

        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
    } 
}
```

**[EDIT]** OK Try like this (different path - a folder on the external storage):

```
    String path =
        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator  + "yourFolder";
    // Create the folder.
    File folder = new File(path);
    folder.mkdirs();

    // Create the file.
    File file = new File(folder, "config.txt");
```

Comment: I can't find my app under data/data

Comment: it's `/data/data/...` not `data/data/...` and it can't be seen with a file explorer, if you don't have root access.

Comment: I'm searching whole phone for config.txt, it can't find anything.

Comment: Do you have **root** access? If not, you can't find it. But you can re-read my updated answer, follow the provided link and save the file where **you** decide to save it.

Comment: No I don't have root access, how can I get it?

Comment: Too broad. Follow my advice: re-save the file in a location of your choice.

Comment: Wait... must open my IDE, which takes time

Comment: Remember: flushing the stream finalizes the writings.

Comment: Thank you very much for this code. How can I combine this code with the code in the question? Thanks.

Comment: I edited my answer as a replacement for your method. Should work AS IS. But you better comment out your method before trying mine. Just in case.

Comment: Thank you but I couldn't find config.txt file in DCIM folder.. There is no  /YourFolder/ folder either..

Comment: Weird. If not existing, the folder (`YourFolder`) is created, under `DCIM` (or `Camera`, depending on the OS version).

Comment: There is not YourFolder under DCIM or Camera, I assure you.

Comment: Can you print out the value of `path.toString()`?

Comment: it is : /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/YourFolder

Comment: And `path.mkdirs();` doesn't create the folder?

Comment: Yes that it is created? Please see my answer edit - just to show that it really should work without problems

Comment: Can we try another path? Thanks.

Comment: I noticed that there is no DCIM folder under /emulated/0, maybe that's the problem..

Comment: Probably, your emulator has been created without a camera. See my edited answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103857/discussion-between-jason-and-hrundi-v-bakshi).

Comment: Currently it creates a folder, but not the file. There is a problem with the code.

Comment: This file : `final File file = new File(path, "config.txt");` never works in the code...

Comment: We're getting there, step by step. It's `final File file = new File(folder, "config.txt");`, not `final File file = new File(path, "config.txt");`

Comment: We are making path but we are not using path when we are writing to the file.

Comment: Did you skip this line `File folder = new File(path);`? I'm talking about the `[EDIT]` portion of my answer.

Comment: OK, I didn't skip that line, but where are we using `folder`? Can you make a complete working code please? Thanks.

Comment: ... in the very next line! `File file = new File(folder, "config.txt");` I start thinking you are really new to programming.

Comment: You are missing something. How are we using `file` ? Thanks.

Comment: Good answer but It really surprises me that every answer skips using a `Buffer`. For efficiency consider wrapping your `OutputStreamWriter` with a `BufferedWriter`.

Comment: @abstractArrow Good point. A more efficient way would be using something like this: `Writer buffOut
   = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fOut));`

Answer (score 5):

Write one text file simplified:

```
private void writeToFile(String content) {
    try {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/test.txt");

        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
        writer.append(content);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This Method takes File name & data String as Input and dumps them in a folder on SD card.
You can change Name of the folder if you want.

The return type is **Boolean** depending upon Success or failure of the FileOperation.

**Important Note: Try to do it in Async Task as FIle IO make cause ANR on Main Thread.**

```
 public boolean writeToFile(String dataToWrite, String fileName) {

            String directoryPath =
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + File.separator
                            + "LOGS"
                            + File.separator;

            Log.d(TAG, "Dumping " + fileName +" At : "+directoryPath);

            // Create the fileDirectory.
            File fileDirectory = new File(directoryPath);

            // Make sure the directoryPath directory exists.
            if (!fileDirectory.exists()) {

                // Make it, if it doesn't exist
                if (fileDirectory.mkdirs()) {
                    // Created DIR
                    Log.i(TAG, "Log Directory Created Trying to Dump Logs");
                } else {
                    // FAILED
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error: Failed to Create Log Directory");
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "Log Directory Exist Trying to Dump Logs");
            }

            try {
                // Create FIle Objec which I need to write
                File fileToWrite = new File(directoryPath, fileName + ".txt");

                // ry to create FIle on card
                if (fileToWrite.createNewFile()) {
                    //Create a stream to file path
                    FileOutputStream outPutStream = new FileOutputStream(fileToWrite);
                    //Create Writer to write STream to file Path
                    OutputStreamWriter outPutStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outPutStream);
                    // Stream Byte Data to the file
                    outPutStreamWriter.append(dataToWrite);
                    //Close Writer
                    outPutStreamWriter.close();
                    //Clear Stream
                    outPutStream.flush();
                    //Terminate STream
                    outPutStream.close();
                    return true;
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error: Failed to Create Log File");
                    return false;
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Exception", "Error: File write failed: " + e.toString());
                e.fillInStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write complete data in logData in File

The File will be create in Downlaods Directory

> This is only for Api 28 and lower .
>
> This will not work on Api 29 and higer

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
public static File createPrivateFile(String logData) {
    String fileName = "/Abc.txt";
    File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/");
    directory.mkdir();
    File file = new File(directory + fileName);
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        if (file.exists()) {
            file.delete();
        }
        file = new File(getAppDir() + fileName);
        file.createNewFile();
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fos.write(logData.getBytes());
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        return file;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```