# Can I save own-class data to a file?

Tags: java, android, oop, saving-data

I tried to save data from my own class to File! My class is

> odmiana

The code looks like that:

```
od = new odmiana(e1.getText().toString(),e2.getText().toString(),e3.getText().toString(),e4.getText().toString(),e5.getText().toString(),e6.getText().toString());
String filename = "myfile";
FileOutputStream outputStream;

try {
    outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    outputStream.write(od);
    outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write a string to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35481924/write-a-string-to-a-file) and don't forget to implement runtime permissions

Comment: but it actually isn`t String, it`s my own class

Comment: You need to use an `ObjectOutputStream`. what does `openFileOutput` do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118751/how-do-i-serialize-an-object-and-save-it-to-a-file-in-android